# How can I allow ssh connection from an IP subnet on port 10022 using iptables?

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall, iptables

I need to set up a server with public IP for bandwidth testing, and I already have a script to drop all incoming traffic except for the ports I need. I have changed the ssh port from default (22) to another one (let's call it XXXXX; sorry for the paranoia but we just got hacked last week).

So my question is how can I allow a range of IP's to ssh into the server through that specific port?

The script I mentioned earlier:

```
iptables -F
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i em1 -p tcp --dport XXXXX -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o em1 -p tcp --sport XXXXX -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o em1 -p tcp --dport XXXXX -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i em1 -p tcp --sport XXXXX -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

So I just need to add the ip range so that I can ssh remotely.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-s` option of `iptables`. It accepts an IP of the form `nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn` or with a mask (`nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn/nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn` or `nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn/nn`). So to allow for example connections from nnn.nnn.nnn.* you can write

```
iptables -A INPUT -s nnn.nnn.nnn.0/255.255.255.0 -i em1 -p tcp --dport XXXXX -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

or

```
iptables -A INPUT -s nnn.nnn.nnn.0/24 -i em1 -p tcp --dport XXXXX -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

(see for example [here](http://jodies.de/ipcalc) for netmask calculation)

If you cannot create a netmask, then I'm afraid you will have to duplicate the rule for each of the IP addresses you want to allow to connect to your server.

In general, though, I never found working with iptables directly very nice, one can quickly loose the overview. I'd probably go for something like [shorewall](http://shorewall.net/).

Comment: If you lose the overview it means likely you're doing it wrong. `ipset` is, for example, an awesome way of staying on top of the complexity, while giving symbolic names to whole sets of IPs, networks or ports or interfaces or combinations of the former *and* speeding up processing compared to adding individual rules instead of referencing an IP set.